# AspNetCore Can't Get Value of Payload In POST Action

Tags: asp.net-core, curl, post, .net-core, http-post

Trying to get a simple post endpoint to read data. I can't seem to figure out how to do the simple task of binding the post payload to the method parameter.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public object Post(string data)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint on Ok(). I'm using cURL to test.

I have tried this command 
`curl -d data:"hello" -X POST http://localhost:80/test`
and this command
`curl -d "hello" -X POST http://localhost:80/test`

The `data` parameter is always null on the breakpoint.

If I add [FromBody] to the parameter:

```
public object Post([FromBody] string data)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

The breakpoint is never reached and asp net core internally returns 400 - The input was not valid. but it doesn't log anything about why the input wasn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

**ASP .net core only supports json payloads in POST by default.**

Since you are attempting to send plain text, you will need to manually obtain the payload from the request. Binding is not supported out of the box.

### This is a solution for getting posted files containing plain text.

Eg. `curl -F data=@test.txt -X POST http://localhost:80/test`

Start by removing the `string data` parameter.

Add this method to your controller:

```
    private string GetPostedFile(string fileName)
    {
        IFormFile data = Request.Form.Files[fileName];
        var bytes = new byte[data.Length];
        var result = data.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(bytes).Result;
        return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
    }
```

Now you can obtain the data, reference the GetPostedFile method in your POST handler like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public object Post()
{
    string data = GetPostedFile("data");
    return Ok();
}
```

This will get the value of your posted file referred to as "data" in the curl command.